# int* to int invalid conversion

Tags: c++, arrays

Trying to make a dice roller for an assignment using 1d and 2d arrays for an assignment for CS and ran into a problem

What I Have so far is this (and yes, i know the boolean structure is bad):

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <ctime>
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <iomanip>

  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
int g[5][5] = {{}};
int d[11] = {};

int die1;
int die2;

srand(time(0));

for ( int roll = 1; roll <= 36000; ++roll )
{
    die1 = 1 + rand() % 6;
    die2 = 1 + rand() % 6;

    if (die1 == 1 && (die2 == 1))
        g[0][0] += 1;

    if (die1 == 1 && die2 == 2)
        g[0][1] += 1;

    if (die1 == 1 && die2 == 3)
        g[0][2] += 1;

    if (die1 == 1 && die2 == 4)
        g[0][3] += 1;

    if (die1 == 1 && die2 == 5)
        g[0][4] += 1;

    if (die1 == 1 && die2 == 6)
        g[0][5] += 1;


    if (die1 == 2 && die2 == 1)
        g[1][0] += 1;

    if (die1 == 2 && die2 == 2)
        g[1][1] += 1;

    if (die1 == 2 && die2 == 3)
        g[1][2] += 1;

    if (die1 == 2 && die2 == 4)
        g[1][3] += 1;

    if (die1 == 2 && die2 == 5)
        g[1][4] += 1;

    if (die1 == 2 && die2 == 6)
        g[1][5] += 1;


    if (die1 == 3 && die2 == 1)
        g[2][0] += 1;

    if (die1 == 3 && die2 == 2)
        g[2][1] += 1;

    if (die1 == 3 && die2 == 3)
        g[2][2] += 1;

    if (die1 == 3 && die2 == 4)
        g[2][3] += 1;

    if (die1 == 3 && die2 == 5)
        g[2][4] += 1;

    if (die1 == 3 && die2 == 6)
        g[2][5] += 1;


    if (die1 == 4 && die2 == 1)
        g[3][0] += 1;

    if (die1 == 4 && die2 == 2)
        g[3][1] += 1;

    if (die1 == 4 && die2 == 3)
        g[3][2] += 1;

    if (die1 == 4 && die2 == 4)
        g[3][3] += 1;

    if (die1 == 4 && die2 == 5)
        g[3][4] += 1;

    if (die1 == 4 && die2 == 6)
        g[3][5] += 1;


    if (die1 == 5 && die2 == 1)
        g[4][0] += 1;

    if (die1 == 5 && die2 == 2)
        g[4][1] += 1;

    if (die1 == 5 && die2 == 3)
        g[4][2] += 1;

    if (die1 == 5 && die2 == 4)
        g[4][3] += 1;

    if (die1 == 5 && die2 == 5)
        g[4][4] += 1;

    if (die1 == 5 && die2 == 6)
        g[4][5] += 1;


    if (die1 == 6 && die2 == 1)
        g[5][0] += 1;

    if (die1 == 6 && die2 == 2)
        g[5][1] += 1;

    if (die1 == 6 && die2 == 3)
        g[5][2] += 1;

    if (die1 == 6 && die2 == 4)
        g[5][3] += 1;

    if (die1 == 6 && die2 == 5)
        g[5][4] += 1;

    if (die1 == 6 && die2 == 6)
        g[5][5] += 1;
}

d[1] = g[0][0];
d[2] = g[1][0] + g[0][1];
d[3] = g[2][0] + g[0][2] + g[1][1];
d[4] = g[3]{0} + g[0][3] + g[1][2] + g[2][1];
d[5] = g[4][0] + g[0][4] + g[2][2] + g[3][1] + g[1][3];
d[6] = g[5][0] + g[0][5] + g[4][1] + g[1][4] + g[3][2] + g[2][3];
```

tried to compile with gnu and got this error on where it begins d[4] = ... at the bottom.

```
    error: invalid conversion from int* to int [-fpermissive]
```

any help would be appreciated, i really need to get this assignment done... Thx

Comment: d[4] = g[3]**{0}** + g[0][3] + g[1][2] + g[2][1];

Comment: Be careful of those curly braces when you mean square brackets ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be a typo but are the braces in the following line correct (bolded for clarity)?

> d[4] = g[3]**{0}** + g[0][3] + g[1][2] + g[2][1];

Should the line be?

> d[4] = g[3]**[0]** + g[0][3] + g[1][2] + g[2][1];